# How do I customize the chart.js tooltip? Two labels have the same data, which I want to show you with each data

Tags: javascript, laravel, chart.js

[image]

I would like to show you the tooltip by adding "%" to the values of KoreaCount and JapanCount respectively. However, both graphs have the same value in return, with only one return. How can I show this as a tooltip for Korea and Japan?`

```
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: ['@lang('home/main.korea')', '@lang('home/main.japan')'],
            datasets: [{
                label: [

                ],
                data: [
                    {!! $koreaPercent !!} ,
                    {!! $japanPercent !!} ,
                ],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'red',
                    'blue',
                ],
            }]
        },
        options: {
            tooltips: {
                enabled: true,
                mode: 'single',
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(tooltipItems, data) { 
                        return {!! $japanPercent !!}+ tooltipItems.yLabel + tooltipItems.xLabel + " %";
            }
        }
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Assuming you've [read the docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html) ?

Comment: yes i read docs/...

Comment: Can you explain _ both graphs have the same value in return, with only one return_ ? Are you trying to make **two separate graphs** with the same value? It might be helpful to see your controller code that's returning the data

Comment: The data has already been received. It is 
{!! $KoreaPercent !} ,{!! $japanPercent !!' Two values, but each one on the graph is a tooltip, and that's the point of this question.

Comment: What i understand: You want to display the data, like `456` concatenated with a `%` char, like `456%`

Comment: Better guess than I had @MateusJunges

Comment: Yes, that's right. I'd like to print a tooltip with a data value of + "%."

Comment: I think i got a solution. Just a moment.

Comment: and there it is

Answer (score 0):

Create a canvas for your chart:

```html
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

This is the required javascript code:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ["Green", "Blue", "Gray", "Purple", "Yellow", "Red", "Black"],
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: [
        "#2ecc71",
        "#3498db",
        "#95a5a6",
        "#9b59b6",
        "#f1c40f",
        "#e74c3c",
        "#34495e"
      ],
      data: [12, 19, 3, 17, 28, 24, 7]
    }]
  },
  options: {
      tooltips : {

      callbacks : { 
        label : function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
                  return  dataset.data[tooltipItem.index] + ' %';
                },
        },
      },
  }
});
```

And [this](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0-rc.1/Chart.js) is the Charts.js cdn that i have used.

Here is the result:

[image: https://imgur.com/gallery/3KszJQY]

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/mateusjunges/akhruj5v/9/) is a working js fiddle.

Hope it helps.